# Inexplicable margin after input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a little [codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/xgBeaJ) which I am working on. And there is just a random margin after an input field. I set

```
*{
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}
```

, so that shouldn't be the reason. Additionally the css of the both input fields:

```
#plannername{
  width:40%;
  background-color:#9eefbc;
  margin-left:20%;
  border:0;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:20px;
}

#plannersubmit{
  width:17%;
  background-color:#6dce91;
  border:0;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:20px;
}
```

As you can see there is not margin, except the `margin-left: 20%` of the `#plannername`. But that shouldn't affect that little margin on the right of it/on the left of the submit button.
What could be causing this little margin???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd> you see that it's actually not a margin but a **single space**.

Here's a great article about it and how to get rid of it: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Most people learn (incorrectly) that all whitespace in your HTML code is ignored. Of course, that can't be the case otherwise you wouldn't be able to separate words from each other. Extraneous white space is "normalized" and that usually means reduced to a single space. Most non-printable characters are normalized (i.e. carriage returns).